# Python TypeError: string indices must be integers in CLASS

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I'm using this code without OOP it works.

But when I want to use it in the class `print(link['href])`, the following error appears:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What is the problem?

```
class Link(object):        
  def get_linkblock(self,url):
    import httplib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    from bs4 import SoupStrainer        
    self.url = url
    print(self.url)        
    self.http = httplib2.Http()
    self.status, self.response = self.http.request(self.url)
    for link in bs(self.response, "lxml", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
      print(link['href']) # <---- PROBLEM IS HERE
```

Comment: What's the output of `print(link)`? Maybe `link` is not a dictionary.

Comment: Your original coed was different. Now you changed it and introduced an error. OOP has nothing to do with that ;)

Comment: link is bs object.with class bs object and without bs object too.i wrote big code but need using different links.because of i want wrote oop.but not works with oop

Comment: print link[1] or link[0]